# Remove WooCommerce styles and scripts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-action, wp-enqueue-scripts

I want to remove Woocommerce scripts and styles from non woocommerce pages. I am trying code below but it's not working. I found the issue why it's not working, because woocommerce not setting priorty on add action. See woocommerce code here
[https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/44d129e45286b782fcce2ba67acf837a46e0c6c9/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php#L43](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'load_scripts' ) );
```

FYI: I tried code below in my functions.php which didn't worked for me.

```
/**
 * Manage WooCommerce styles and scripts.
 */
function grd_woocommerce_script_cleaner() {
    
    // Remove the generator tag
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $GLOBALS['woocommerce'], 'generator' ) );

    // Unless we're in the store, remove all the cruft!
    if ( ! is_woocommerce() && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_frontend_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-general');
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-layout' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-smallscreen' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_fancybox_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_chosen_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_prettyPhoto_css' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'selectWoo' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'selectWoo' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-payment-method' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lost-password' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc_price_slider' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-credit-card-form' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-chosen' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'woocommerce' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto-init' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-blockui' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-placeholder' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-payment' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'fancybox' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jqueryui' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'grd_woocommerce_script_cleaner', 999 );
```

Remove woocommerce scripts from no woocommerce pages

Comment: If you don’t specify the priority as the fourth argument to the `add_action` function, it defaults to `10`. So you have to set the priority higher than 10 to dequeue the scripts.

Comment: Also, you best remove the script by both `deregister_script` and `dequeue_script` for every script.

Comment: @Klaassiek Yeah you are right about default priority. But if you see my code above I already added priority 999 which is higher than 10. But it didn't work for me. Please see my answer below to remove scripts. Please upvote if it's helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, use the action below to remove WC scripts. **I tested on Woocommerce Version 4.7.4 and it's working great.**

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'conditionally_disable_wc_assets');
/**
    * Remove WC stuff on non WC pages.
    */
function conditionally_disable_wc_assets()
{
    if (IF_CONDTION_MET) {
        // remove WC generator tag
        remove_filter('get_the_generator_html', 'wc_generator_tag', 10, 2);
        remove_filter('get_the_generator_xhtml', 'wc_generator_tag', 10, 2);
        // unload WC scripts
        remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'load_scripts']);
        remove_action('wp_print_scripts', [WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'localize_printed_scripts'], 5);
        remove_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', [WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'localize_printed_scripts'], 5);
        // remove "Show the gallery if JS is disabled"
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wc_gallery_noscript');
    }
}
```